# Get concrete type that derives from generic type, regardless of the generic type parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return a type that derives from a generic type and a specific interface, but I don't care what the generic type parameter is on the base class. Here is the concrete type:

```
public class TrackerJobData : DataAccessLayerBase<ProdDataDataContext>, ITrackerJobData
```

And this is my query to try and get the concrete type:

```
Type foundType = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                  where type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))
                     && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DataAccessLayerBase))
                  select type).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is that `foundType` is always `null`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That shouldn't compile, unless you've got a separate non-generic class `DataAccessLayerBase` somewhere, I think.

Comment: Ha. You're right, and I do. That's why it's returning null. But the question still remains. Is it possible to get a concrete type that derives from DataAccessLayerBase<T>?

Comment: The point of generics is that you can use things on a contract basis rather than a concrete type basis. If you're trying to extract the concrete type, your design is probably faulty. I'd just make sure that whatever you're trying to do is part of an interface constraint on the generic type in question. Any combination of a generic type and a `typeof` or `GetType` is a code smell.

Comment: We're trying to load a DI container with the data access classes based on a (generic) base class specified in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a recursive function to check if a class derives from `DataAccessLayerBase<T>` for some `T` by manually walking up `Type.BaseType`:

```
static bool IsDataAccessLayer(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    return (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DataAccessLayerBase<>))
        || (type.BaseType != null && IsDataAccessLayer(type.BaseType));
}
```

Comment: I got this working, but the problem is the hard-coded `DataAccessLayerBase<>`. That defeats the purpose of being able to specify the type in the config file.

Comment: @BobHorn The parentheses you included aren't necessary, the code was valid the way it was. You can avoid hardcoding `DataAccessLayerBase<>` by adding a second parameter of type `Type`, and making sure the second argument comes from a configuration file, or anything else you can think of.

Comment: Actually, there was one parenthesis missing at the beginning of the OR. I unnecessarily added the ones around the first part, just for me. ;) I'm still working on it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Heh, thanks, missed that. What I *meant* to write had one less `)` at the end :)

Comment: +1 for the tip. I solved this in a bit of a different way, which I will post as the answer. You got me thinking in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Since my base class is specified in the config file, this is the setting:

```
<add key="dataAccessBaseClass" value="Company.Core.Components.Data.L2S.DataAccessLayerBase`1[], Company.Core.Components"/>
```

Notice the empty brackets `[]`. That signifies a generic class but does not specify the type. I discovered this by trial and error.

And here is the implementation:

```
Type dataAccessBaseClass = Type.GetType(_dataAccessBaseClass);

Type foundType = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                  where type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))                                         
                  && type.BaseType.Name.LeftOf('`') == dataAccessBaseClass.Name.LeftOf('`')
                  select type).FirstOrDefault();
```

`_dataAccessBaseClass` is the string from the config file.
`T` is the interface type, which doesn't really have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: I appreciate that this may do what you want, but it isn't what you asked. This won't match if class `B` derives from `A` which derives from `DataAccessLayerBase<something>`, and this will match if class `B` derives from some other `DataAccessLayerBase<something>` than the one specified in the config file. (It may not matter to you, but it will matter for others that have the same question, find yours, and read the answers.)

Comment: Your first comment is a good point, and we'll have to eventually deal with that issue. Your second comment is covered in the title of my question: "regardless of the generic type parameter." We aren't specifying a generic type parameter in the config file; just that it's a generic class in the first place.

Comment: That isn't what I meant. I meant that you can have two different generic types `DataAccessLayerBase<T>`, specify one of them in the configuration file, use the other one as a base class, and your check will say it derives from specified type.

Comment: Ah, right. We're okay with that (I think) because that really shouldn't happen.

Comment: @BobHorn: Saying something shouldn't happen in software development?

Comment: LOL. I know, man. I know. We're already handling it. We're going to throw an exception if we find more than one instance.